# действие перед закрытием консоли

Tags: python

Нужна программа, которая будет выполнять действия после закрытия консоли.Например идёт исполнение кода,
после этого пользователь выходит из консоли, и программа должна выполнить некоторые действия. Подскажите модули на python чтобы это реализовать.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Начинайте писать свою программу.

Comment: @strawdog прошу прощение, хотел узнать какие есть для этого модули

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы можем отслеживать процесс консоли, и когда он завершится выполнять действия. Для мониторинга процессов можно использовать [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil).

Answer (score 1):

можно с помощью структуры `try` отследить нажатие `CTRL + C`, выполнить что нужно и закрыть программу с помощью `sys.exit()`.